# Plackup cannot use specific perl version

Tags: perl, perlbrew

My application is using plackup and it required perl version 5.16 for my app can run well. I used perlbrew  to downgrade current perl version(5.18) to 5.16 then here is perl --version output

```
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 0 (v5.16.0) built for darwin-2level
```

(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

But my app still include perl 5.18 and shows this error

> Can't locate Text/MicroTemplate.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Text::MicroTemplate module) (@INC contains: lib ./lib /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .)

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `which plackup` to find the plackup script, then change the first line to use the full path of your Perl 5.16 install.

Comment: I found it, I forget to run perlbrew before plackup. Thanks for your help.